# Vertical Alignment on JQuery Mobile Grid

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am attempting to set up a page using JQuery Mobile, where I have a 3 column grid, with a label, a text input and a set of horizonally-aligned radio-buttons.  For some reason Grid-element c sets it's height larger than the other 2, and I can't seem to force the first 2 cells to align with it.

An example of the code is at: http://jsfiddle.net/5WSj4/1/

Here is the code in question

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_fullDialog">
    <div id="dialog_main" data-role="content">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:30%">
                <label style="vertical-align:top" data-mini="true" for="leagueNameInput">League Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:10%">
                <input type="text" style="vertical-align:top" data-mini="true" name="leagueNameInput" id="leagueNameInput" maxlength="4" value="" data-mini="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:60%; text-align: right;">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-mini="true">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                        <!-- <legend>Difficulty:</legend>  -->
                        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="difficultyEasy" value="choice-1" />
                        <label for="difficultyEasy">Easy</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="difficultyMedium" value="choice-2" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="difficultyMedium">Medium</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="difficultyHard" value="choice-2" />
                        <label for="difficultyHard">Hard</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For some bizarre reason, ui-controlgroup has a top margin of 0.5em. Overriding it in the fieldset element solves the problem, i.e.

```
style="margin-top: 0px;"
```